# How can I use ROW_NUM() to pick one instance where it doesn't have a second record?

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

I am trying to use ROW_NUM() to get me instances of ID's that have only 1 associated comment value which is like 'SEND Final' and that's it.

This is an example of the records in a table:

| Comment | ID |
| --- | --- |
| SEND Final | 1 |
| SEND Draft | 1 |
| SEND Final | 2 |
| SEND Draft | 2 |
| SEND Final | 3 |

After running my code (below output table) I expect this to be returned since it is the only record in the table that has just one instance of comment that is like 'SEND Final' (No record/value like 'SEND Draft' associated with the ID).

| Comment | ID |
| --- | --- |
| SEND Final | 3 |

Here is what I have now that successfully partitions how I want it to, but I am having trouble with the logic of choosing the records that fit my criteria.

```
SELECT *, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) Row_num
FROM Mytable
GROUP BY Comment, ID
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

I've made a dbfiddle with some test data and also code. It is found [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/mVaTyacE)

Any help is greatly appreciated or if I am going about this the wrong way, please let me know!

Comment: You wouldn't, you'd use `COUNT`.

Comment: @ThomA Yup, someone posted an answer using this. I am not very experienced with SQL and didn't know you could use COUNT with partition! Thank you!

Comment: @Krasnips the official documentation explains it all, shows you all the window and analytic functions etc.

Comment: Pro-tip, make your question title about the problem you are trying to solve, not the solution you can't make work. Cos I note both this and your previous question titles focused on the solution you were trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you are using `row_number` when you want a `count`?

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        Comment,
        ID,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) count_num
   FROM Mytable
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE count_num = 1
-- Maybe the following line is required? The sample data isn't clear on that
AND Comment = 'SEND Final';
```

Comment: You probably need to add `AND Comment = 'SEND Final'`

Comment: @siggemannen you beat me to it! Thank you both!

Comment: @DaleK Thank you for the answer! And yup I didn't even think about adding a case to need a clause for comment being equal to 'SEND Final'. I am still new to SQL and I believe I overthink a lot of this! Thank you again!